# Prevent ruby/rails from printing results of assignment expressions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb

When I do something like this in rails:

```
irb(main):060:0> users = User.where(name: "Joe")
```

The console will evaluate `users` and print it out (maybe with `inspect`, or `to_s`, I'm not 100% sure). This results in hundreds of lines of output that I don't really want.

I know I can do something like this to prevent the output on one specific line:

```
irb(main):060:0> users = User.where(name: "Joe"); nil
```

Because `nil` will be evaluated and printed out instead of `users`.

I could also turn off all evaluations with:

```
irb(main):060:0> conf.echo = false
```

The first solutions is annoying because you have to remember to add that on every line you want to suppress output. And the second is annoying, because sometimes you do want output. Many times you just want to type the name of a variable to have it printed.

Python doesn't seem to have this problem. If I type `a = {1: 2}`, the python shell doesn't evaluate `a`, it just shows the prompt again. But if I type `{1: 2}` or just `a`, it does print out the value.

It seems like python's console checks whether there's a left-hand-side of the statement being evaluated to decide whether to print the result or not.

#### Question:

Can something like that be done in ruby's console? So that statements like `a = {1 => 2}` are not evaluated, but statements like `a` and `{1 => 2}` are?

#### Update:

I pushed this merge request to the irb repo, perhaps it'll be accepted and then there *will* be a way: https://github.com/ruby/irb/pull/12 .

Comment: Python behaves this way because there assignment is a _statement_ (that is, doesn't have value). In ruby assignment is an expression, with everything that this entails.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yeah, I see what you're saying. Also if a python expression returns `None` the console doesn't print anything. I just with there was a way to prevent irb from printing the output of an expression if the expression was assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit:

A version of the MR referenced below was merged to irb, but tweaked a few times since then. So to get the behavior you want it depends on the irb version:

If you have at least `1.2.0`, but less than `1.2.6`: the default behavior is to *not* print anything for assignment statements. You have to set `IRB.conf[:ECHO_ON_ASSIGNMENT] = true` if you want the old behavior (of always printing everything).

If you have `1.2.6`, the default value for `ECHO_ON_ASSIGNMENT` was changed to `true`, and a new config value: `OMIT_ON_ASSIGNMENT` was added which will truncate long output for assignment statements, it defaults to `true`. So you have to set `IRB.conf[:ECHO_ON_ASSIGNMENT] = false` if you don't want anything to be printed for assignment statements. You have to set `IRB.conf[:OMIT_ON_ASSIGNMENT] = false` if you want the old behavior (of always printing everything).

If you have `1.2.7` or above, `OMIT_ON_ASSIGNMENT` was removed in favor of letting `ECHO_ON_ASSIGNMENT` accept `true`, `false`, or `:truncate`, with the default value being `:truncate`. A value of `true` will print everything for assignment statements, `false` will print nothing, and `:truncate` will print a truncated version (like setting `OMIT_ON_ASSIGNMENT` to `true` in `1.2.6`).

Note that the versions above versions of the *irb* gem, not ruby versions (even though `irb` is included in ruby's standard library). You can check what version of `irb` you have by looking at `IRB::VERSION`. Very old versions of `irb` don't set this constant, so if it's missing, you definitely have a version lower than `1.2.0`.

#### Original answer:

Until [this pull request](https://github.com/ruby/irb/pull/12) (or one like it) is merged, you can put the following into your `~/.irbrc` file:

```rb
require 'ripper'
module IRB
  class Irb
    ASSIGNMENT_NODE_TYPES = [:assign, :opassign, :massign]
    def assignment_expression?(line)
      ASSIGNMENT_NODE_TYPES.include?(Ripper.sexp(line)&.dig(1,-1,0))
    end

    def output_value # :nodoc:
      return if assignment_expression?(@context.last_line)
      printf @context.return_format, @context.inspect_last_value
    end
  end

  class Context
    attr_accessor :last_line
    def evaluate(line, line_no, exception: nil) # :nodoc:
      @line_no = line_no
      @last_line = line
      if exception
        line = "begin ::Kernel.raise _; rescue _.class; #{line}; end"
        @workspace.local_variable_set(:_, exception)
      end
      set_last_value(@workspace.evaluate(self, line, irb_path, line_no))
    end
  end
end
```

Note that since this monkey-patches `IRB::Irb` and `IRB::Context`, there's no guarantee that it will be compatible with future releases.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is caused by the fact that in Ruby assignment returns the assigned value automatically, i.e.

```
a = 1
#=> 1
```

If you dig into documentation for `conf.echo` you will see that it is used to control whatever to print return value or not.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named `.irbrc` in your `~` folder, or in your current folder. Inside, add:

```
IRB.conf[:ECHO] = false
```

That should disable echo.

If you `puts IRB.conf` you'll see other settings you can adjust as well.

More info is found in the [irb documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html#module-IRB-label-Configuration)

Comment: That's not _quite_ what's being asked though. They only want to suppress output from assignments.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that's a good distinction, I glossed over that when I was reading. I don't think there's a setting for that behavior in IRB but this might be good enough for now. I just add a `;` after a statement (in pry) when I want to suppress output